# Problems with OAuth and 500px API with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth

Thought I would play around with OAuth to learn and I'm having a bit of issues trying to get it to work. Not much information on the developer page for 500px and everything I've searched through on Google hasn't solved my problem yet and hope I can find an answer here. Any help I could get here would be greatly appreciated since I'm stuck!

The error I keep receiving is 401 Unauthorized

I've set up a TestController to mess with the API.

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("KEY", "SECRET",
      :site               => "https://api.500px.com",
      :request_token_path => "/v1/oauth/request_token",
      :access_token_path  => "/v1/oauth/access_token",
      :authorize_path     => "/v1/oauth/authorize")

    session[:consumer] = consumer

    session[:request_token] = session[:consumer].get_request_token(:oauth_callback => "http://localhost:3000/auth/500px/callback")
    redirect_to session[:request_token].authorize_url
  end

  def callback
    session[:oauth_token] = params["oauth_token"]
    session[:oauth_verifier] = params["oauth_verifier"]
    session[:access_token] = session[:consumer].get_access_token(session[:request_token], :oauth_token => session[:oauth_token], :oauth_verifier => session[:oauth_verifier])
  end
end
```

Comment: is that really `consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("KEY", "SECRET",`, and not `consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(ENV[ "KEY" ], ENV[ 'SECRET' ],`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The problem was that in my URL it was localhost:3000 and in my callback URL it was 127.0.0.1:3000. Figured they would be the same but not the case. As soon as I changed the callback URL to localhost:3000, it worked. I've updated the code for anyone in the future working with the 500px api.